# Laggy Finder on 10.13.6

Tags: finder, high-sierra

New 27" iMac just a couple of months old. This thing is usually FAST, it's 4.2Ghz Core i7 with 40GB RAM.

Recently doing some file renaming en-masse using an app from The App Store (Name Mangler 3) I noticed how slow the finder is.

Here is video evidence of what's happening: (watch the full 15 seconds or so).

[image]

The only things I can think of are:

1. I originally downloaded the free trial of Name Mangler from their website rather than app store. Given this version wouldn't be sandboxed the same was as the App Store version, could this be messing things up?
2. We have also corporate Sophos Endpoint which was recently installed - could that be involved?

The slowness does tend to seem to be connected mostly to file access, rather than generally (it still renders After Effects videos like a champ).